# Asynchronous call not refreshing table

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I'm noticing some very weird behavior, I'm hoping to see if anyone else has come across this. I am making an asynchronous api call (code below). When the call completes an array is populated from the results of the call, and then I reload my table (which should cause `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be called), which should update my table view with my array's data. However, the data in the tableview still doesn't appear until it needs to be reloaded from some other means - for instance, if I change views by clicking on a tab and then going back to the original view. It seems like there is some aspect of "refreshing the table" that I am missing, however I am calling `reloadData` when the asynchronous call returns.

Code:

```
-(void)refreshWeeksOffers
{
    [array removeAllObjects];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =
        [WebRequests createPostRequestWithApiCall:@"getResults" bodyData:@"params={\"locale\" : \"US\"}"];

    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
         {
             // parse home page offers from resulting json
             JsonParser *parser = [[JsonParser alloc] initWithData:data];
             array = [parser parseHomepageResults];

             [self.topWeekTable reloadData];

         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
         }
         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
         }

     }];

    [self.topWeekTable reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    Offer *currentOffer = (Offer *)[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%% Back", currentOffer.advertisedRate];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:currentOffer.storeImage];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    cell.imageView.image = img;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are invoking UIKit from a background thread, which is not supported.

Try this:

```
[ self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector( reloadData ) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO ] ;
```

Another strategy which I prefer is like this:

```
-(void)startAsyncSomething
{
    [ obj operationWithAsyncHandler:^{
        [ [ NSThread mainThread ] performBlock:^{
            ... handle completion here ...
        } ]
    }]
}
```

You can add `-performBlock:` to **NSThread** with a category something like this:

```
@implementation NSThread (BlockPerforming)

-(void)performBlock:(void(^)())block
{
    if ( !block ) { return ; }
    [ self performSelector:@selector( performBlock: ) onThread:self withObject:[ block copy ] waitUntilDone:NO ] ;
}

@end
```

Comment: The first solution gets annoying for more complex situations, so I prefer the second which I added as an edit.